# Найти количество значащих бит в числе

Tags: c++, строки, системы-счисления

мне нужно указать количество бит числа в десятичной системе счисления для `bitset`, но я не знаю заранее какое будет число. Я пробовал через `log2(x)+1`, но оно вертает значение `double`, `sizeof(int)` но оно даёт только 4 бита, вот моя функция:

```
void to_binary(int n)
{
string binary = bitset<sizeof(int)>(n).to_string();
cout<<binary;
}
```

Comment: Чем не устраивает double?

Comment: а что не так с sizeof(int)? n всегда int, int чаще всего 4 байта, в чем проблема?)

Comment: @Эникейщик, проблема в том что bitset выпрашивает константу, а если я в < > впишу логарифм, то ошибка «аргумет double неуместен с параметром <size_t> или я что-то делаю неправильно?

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko например, чтобы объявить число 90 в двоичной системе счисления мне нужно, вроде бы, 6 бит, а не 4

Comment: 4 байта, а не 4 бита. Результат sizeof на 8 умножьте.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, почему-то мне кажется, что он на самом деле хочет `bitset<n>`...

Comment: @МихайлоКуриця double элементарно переводится в int

Comment: @МихайлоКуриця так напишите функцию, которая в цикле while делит ваше число на два, пока не останется нолик, и считает количество итераций деления. Как раз таки это число и будет вашим количеством бит

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, именно так и хочу, но реализации я такой не видел и сам придумать не могу

Comment: @МихайлоКуриця Не понял. Что не так с `sizeof(n)*8`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat так как я не знаю длину числа, которое будет введено, то для одного числа этого  места будет мало, а для одного много

Comment: Если битсет слишком большой, это не страшно. А слишком маленьким он быть не может, потому что большее число не влезет в `int n`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не знаю проблема это консоли или нет(задание у меня с формами представления двоичного числа в машинах числения), например, число 90 в консоле я вижу, как 0000000001011010, а должен 1011010

Comment: Нет, это не проблема консоли. Придется отрезать нули руками. Размер bitset-а должен быть известен во время компиляции, поэтому никакой `log2(x)+1` вы туда не засуните. Еще вариант - преобразовать в двоичный вид руками, без битсета...

Comment: По-моему, вместо чтоб спросить, как забить гвоздь, вы пытаетесь выяснить, какой рукой держать для этого микроскоп. В чем ваша **настоящая** проблема? Какова **исходная** задача, для которой вы пытаетесь приспособить логарифм и bitset?

Comment: @Harry задача перевести число в упакованый/неупакованый формат, прямой, обратный, дополнительные коды, мой препод не принял роботу, потому что, если есть число 00011, то у меня было 11, решил эту проблему через битсет, но теперь проблема, что каждое число имеет свою длину в двоичном коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, вы хотите что-то вроде этого:

```
void to_binary(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0) cout << "0" ; else
    {
        string binary;
        while(n)
        {
            binary = char('0' + n%2) + binary;
            n >>= 1;
        }
        cout << binary;
    }
}
```

Нет?